# Comagma, Bimagma and their relation to Jónsson-Tarski algebra.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, universal-algebra

There doesn't seem to be any mention of something like a comagma: the categorical dual of a magma where the arrows are reversed for • : A × A → A, as in π : A → A × A. Only coalgebras and bialgebras are mentioned, but they have extra requirements for identity and associativity.

If comagmas exist, then a bimagma could be constructed from a set S with (S, •, π) where π(•(x,y)) = (x,y) and •(π(x,y)) = (x,y). This is the same structure as a Jónsson-Tarski algebra.

Are these valid assumptions, and are comagma and bimagma known structures that have been studied?

Comment: What do you mean by "exist"?  You can make whatever definition you want...

Comment: @EricWofsey exist in the sense that they are well known, studied, and structurally valid.

Comment: I have no idea what "structurally valid" means.  They certainly aren't _well_-known, but a simple google search shows that the terms have been used before.

Comment: @Neal Alexander it's hard to defend the claim that even magmas are well-studied, since the structure is too weak to admit much theory.

Comment: Actually, comagmas *are* coalgebras, in a wider sense of the term (just as magmas are themselves algebraic structures, aka 'algebras'), but they are coalgebras for a comonad. Nevertheless, if I understand well what a comagma is, it can be seen as a pair of unary operations $p_1,p_2:A\to A$. And algebras with unary operations, I guess, are well studied. Does the converse $\bullet(\pi(x))=x$ also hold? Shouldn't your $x$ in the identity be a pair $(x_1,x_2)$?

Comment: @Berci The converse does hold. x was a pair (edited).